Are there specific rules about what can be edited when the author is no longer active? (In particular changes that would allow reopening.)
What is the significance of Noah, after the flood, getting drunk and cursing his son who saw him Naked?
is currently in the reopen queue (I'm not aware of a way to find out who voted for it).
As it stands, it shouldn't be reopened, but it would be trivial to make it much more acceptable:
Change the question from "What is the significance of Noah …?"
to "Do any denominations have a redemptive interpretation of this passage?".
The problem is that the question is over a decade old and the author has been absent for over a year.
Is it acceptable for me to make such a change, or would that go against policy?

What is the recommended editing that would help get the essence of a specific question reopened?
is a completely different question.

In general, substantive edits should not be made to other people's posts without their input.
However for that question in particular, even if it was the original author who edited it in such a way, we'd have to roll back the edit. The problem with editing that question is that it would invalidate the existing answers.
The right course of action for a question like this is to re-ask it in a form that meets the current scoping rules.
